# About add Customized View

Tags: android, view

I want add customized View to ScrollView. In customized View, Only two methods are described, constructor and onDraw(). But the image that drew in onDraw(), isn't show on ScrollView. What's wrong in my program?

Comment: This could probably have been a comment on my answer to your other question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to override `onMeasure()` so the view can be sized appropriately. Otherwise it might help if you post some code with your question.